# How we can use CUR decomposition in place of SVD decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, matrix-factorization

I have understood how [CUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUR_matrix_approximation) and [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) works, but have not been able to understand the following.

1. How can we use CUR in place of the SVD decomposition?
2. Do the $C$ and $R$ matrices in the CUR follow the same properties as those of $U$ and $V$ matrices in the SVD decomposition?

If we want to reduce the dimension of the original matrix, say, from $n$ to $k$, which matrix of CUR we can use to project original matrix, so that we will get $k$-dimensional data points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVD decomposition:

$$
A_{m\times n}= U_{m\times m} \Sigma_{m\times n}V^{H}_{n\times n}
$$
Here, $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices of left- and right singular vectors, and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing real singular values in a decreasing order.

In your application, you are using a *truncated* SVD (rank $k$), thus
$$
A_{m\times n}\approx U_{m\times k} \Sigma_{k\times k}V^{H}_{k\times n}
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are parts of unitary matrices containing left and right singular vectors corresponding to $k$ largest singular values.

Compare that to a $k$-rank CUR decomposition:
$$
A_{m\times n}\approx C_{m\times k} U_{k\times k}R_{k\times n}
$$

- $C$ and $R$ in CUR decomposition contain $k$ columns and $k$ rows of $A$. Since rank-$k$ CUR decomposition is not unique, different CUR decomposition will feature different rows\columns.
- Entries of $C$ and $R$ *come directly from* $A$ and have an easy interpretation, as opposed to entries of $U$ and $V$ in SVD decomposition.
- $C$ and $R$ are *not unitary* in any way, as opposed to $U$ and $V$ in SVD decomposition.
- $U$ in CUR decomposition is a *full $k\times k$ matrix*, as opposed to a *real diagonal $k\times k$ matrix* $\Sigma$.

So, taking into account that, I would not say that $C$ and $R$ in CUR decomposition follow the same properties as $U$ and $V$ in SVD decomposition. I would say, the only property that is the same between them is their dimensions ($m\times k$ and $k\times n$ in the rank-$k$ case).

Now, how can you use CUR instead of SVD. Instead of using a **unique** (not discussing repeating singular values) rank-$k$ SVD decomposition, that provides you with the best rank-$k$ approximation (in the Frobenius-norm sense), you will have to use **one-of-many** CUR decomposition. Depending on your purpose, you may want to choose one subset of CUR decomposition over the other, that is very problem- and algorithm dependent.

Comment: Can you please explain, which matrix (C or R) we can use to reduce the dimension of original data?

Comment: Usually, you would use both, to select $k$ columns and rows in $C$ and $R$, respectively. Technically, nothing prohibits you to use a CUR decomposition by taking $k_1$ columns from $C$ and $k_2$ rows in $R$ and adjusting $U$ accordingly. But I never saw that in action (might not have enough experience).

Comment: Is there any special formula to choose the values of $r$ and $c$, the number of rows and column to sample from original matrix $A$?

Comment: Please, don't use comments to ask new questions. But you are effectively asking a question, is there a formula to estimate the rank of the matrix.